# htaccess rewrite rule - non-standard URL - question mark after root domain?

Tags: .htaccess

Going in circles trying to get correct convention with no success...How would I redirect the following scenario:

```
 http://www.domain.com/?page=FINDUS
```

to

```
 http://www.domain.com/findus.php
```

Comment: Which of these does your _end user_ see?

Comment: Could you post your current htaccess?

Comment: sorry, end user sees: http://www.domain.com/findus.php